# Calling TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient method from multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

In most of the examples I have come so far, when a server is dealing with multiple clients concurrently the following code is given as example

```
int port = 13000;
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
server.Start();

while (true) {
    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
    // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
    //Do stuff
}
```

In order to increase my throughput under heavy loads, at least that is what I am hoping to achieve, I was thinking of calling AcceptTcpClient method in 4 or so threads. However, I am not sure if that is thread-safe, or that is even suggested way of using it?

The case that I am worried is when I get a burst of connection, like hundreds of clients are connecting to my server. Moreover, when I have look at the [Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.start?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_TcpListener_Start_System_Int32_) method of TcpClient, I noticed backlog argument as well. Using backlog is the better way? Should I just listen on a single thread and leave the heavy handling to the backlog algorithm?

Comment: Is TCP a requirement? WebSocket might be a suitable replacement for you. It has better performance.

Comment: WebSockets is protocol that relies on TCP streamed connection.

Comment: Exactly... TCP is way more efficient if implemented correctly.The Web socket layer kinda takes care of itself. Usually its better to go with websocket unless you particularly need the customization that comes along with the TCP. I am trying to understand your concern exactly. Are you worried a single thread might not be able to respond to incoming connection requests or the capability of TcpClient's backlog to do so?

Comment: I am concerned that for my Client - Server application listening on a single thread may or may not be enough for a burst of connection coming concurrently.

Comment: If you are doing synchronous, there is a large change a single thread wont be enough if large amount of incoming connections suddenly increase. The best way to handle this is keep the listener in a separate thread accept the connection and pass it to another thread which will operate/process it. This makes sure you don't actually start piling up connections by your thread doing something else in the mean time.

Comment: @NarendranPandian Thanks for your input. What you are mentioning is a couple of steps further. I am well aware of how to handle at that point. However, what I am curious is accepting the connections step :)

Comment: Hi! Could you answer if you have found any working solution yet please ?

Comment: @DmitryBoyko, sorry for my late answer! Well, the question is 2 years old now bu based on the test I have done since then I remember that you can safely `AcceptTcpClient` on different threads to increase your throughput!